# Can't get emails into Outlook client

Tags: outlook, pop3, hmailserver

I have moved hMailServer onto a different server. When I use Outlook and log the communication within hMailServer I get the following;

```
Creating session 737
...
SENT: +OK POP3
RECEIVED: CAPA
....
SENT: +OK Mailbox locked and ready
RECEIVED: STAT
SENT: +OK 13 336402
RECEIVED: UIDL
SENT: +OK 13 messages ....
RECEIVED: LIST
SENT: +OK 13 messages ...
SENT: 1 ....
RECEIVED: QUIT
SENT: +OK POP3 server saying goodbye...
Ending session 736
```

So, if I am understanding it correctly Outlook asks for a list of emails but never actually requests that they be downloaded ( "retr 1" is missing)

I don't think it will make any difference, but the server configuration I have required that I port forward 110 as 1100 to make the comms work. It seems to connect and have a conversation so that seems to be working.
Anyone got an idea as to why it doesn't request the messages to be downloaded?